# Cooling timescale for an interstellar dust grain

Tags: temperature, radiation, interstellar-medium, dust, black-body

I would like to estimate the cooling timescale for an interstellar dust grain, starting at 200K, down to 100 K.

The equation I have come up with is:

$\displaystyle t_{cooling} = \frac{mC\Delta T}{Q_{rad}P}$

where:

- $m$ = grain mass ($=1.3\times 10^{-14}$ kg)
- $C$ = specific heat capacity ($=2000$ J kg$^{-1}$ K $^{-1}$)
- $T$ = change in temperature ($= 200-100 = 100 \text{ K}$)
- $Q_{rad}$ = emission efficiency
- $P$ = radiative power of dust grain

**My question is: How do I determine the emission efficiency $Q_{rad}$?**

From *'The Physics and Chemistry of the Interstellar Medium (Tielens 2005)'*, for grains with sizes less than 1$\mu$m, the Planck mean efficiency, <$Q_P(T_d)$>, is given by:

<$Q_P(T_d)$> $=$ $\displaystyle 1.25 \times 10^{-5} T_d^2 \frac{a}{1\mu m} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{(eq. 5.35)}$

Is this analogous to the emission efficiency? Using my values I get <$Q_P(T_d)$> $=0.5$

Comment: Mysterious!  I would have guessed that "emission efficiency" meant ratio of emissivity compared with a perfect black-body surface.   But what does "radiative power" mean?   Also,  perhaps this lecture will be helpful:    https://w.astro.berkeley.edu/~ay216/08/NOTES/Lecture06-08.pdf

Comment: Maybe also https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/145/3/249/2602791  -- clickable link to the PDF there